# How generate pages with different query string in nuxt site?

Tags: nuxt.js

I use nuxt 2.15 and *target: 'static'* in nuxt.config.js My site have a pagination with routes like this:

/product/categyId?page=1
/product/categyId?page=2
...

All workink ok, but *nuxt generate* did only one page /product/categyId without query string variations. I found in nuxt documentation that

> $route.query will always be equal to {} on server-side rendering

Is there a way for resolve this issue? Without changing routing like /product/categoryId/page/num ?

Comment: The better question is, why do you want to do this? Let's say you have 100 pages, do you really want to generate a static page for each? Rather why not take advantage of the SPA Fallback in Nuxt.

Comment: bhaskar, I want a check, how nuxt will generate couple thousands of pages. If all be fast and good - may be this way will implement in production

Comment: Well @tolyan nuxt can generate hundreds of pages without compromising its performance but the thing is, I'm not sure if it generates page for different query string as well, I'm pretty sure that it generates the same for different route parameters but not for route query, are you sure it is going to generate pages for different query string as well?

Comment: @Helper, I checked this. Nuxt generated pages with same content for urls like /category/1?page=1 /category/1?page=2 /category/1?page=n...

Comment: So it's actually not possible?